# Teradata hash MD5 usage

Tags: hash, teradata, md5

I need to hash a column in a teradata table by hash_md5, I tried this

`select hash_md5(COLUMN_NAME) from TABLE`

but it seems not worked like this way. Could anyone suggest please?

Comment: This is not a builtin function in Teradata, it must be installed. See https://downloads.teradata.com/download/extensibility/md5-message-digest-udf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use select **SYSUDTLIB**.hash_md5(COLUMN_NAME) from TABLE

Comment: ... if it's installed :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install MD5 UDF first than you can use it.

Please follow the instructions mentioned in below link

https://downloads.teradata.com/download/extensibility/md5-message-digest-udf?check_logged_in=1